# how can I make a copy of a primitive types c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I ment I want to copy the value of a constant primitive type, and assigned to a reference. I want to do so whthout make it in the heap is that posible?

make some thing like this:

```
const unsigned long rawnan[2]={0xffffffff, 0x7fffffff};
const double NaN = *( double* )rawnan;
    Class{
        float &_f;
        inline Class( ):_f(float(NaN)){
        }
    }
```

and I want to know if when:

```
Class{
    float &_f;
    inline Class( float F):_f(float(F)){
    }
}
```

if I actually making a copy of the of the variable F or not (I know could reference directly to F but I think it scope will end at the end of the constructor then I need to make a copy of it value.)

(if the code not compile, it is because is a pseudo-code from a real code, the fundament question is the important, I hope is understandable)

(I do the deffinition of NaN so, because is the best way so far I know to do it and be compatible with VC++ and G++)

Comment: This is a pseudo code, you should give example with real code.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You seem to be mixing 'double' and 'float' in your example. Do you want to initialize a constant to the binary value of a 'float' NaN or a 'double' NaN?

Comment: tjameson is complicated. I is a cuestion of inherence, I want that that the child class point the same place that it father. That means I when the child class constructor using a object of the father class the internal values must point to the same locations. Because I want when the father object is change is children copy object change too

Comment: @S.C.Madsen and? yes I mix them, but it make a cast automaticaly, this is tested at least work in VC++

Comment: @user1739342: "the child class constructor using a object of the father class" -- use a protected data member in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
float first = 3.14159265358979324f;
float second = first;
```

Comment: First is not a const value, second I cant do that on the constructor as is made in the example:

Comment: @user1739342 You can write code in the constructor body as well. Just assign its argument to a member variable.

Comment: But is a reference for when the body is call _f must reference something. So I have to link it to give a reference firs, and I dont wnat to do it by a new

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your code snippets is correct.

`float(NaN)` and `float(F)` are temporary objects. You bind them to the reference data member `_f`, but this does not extend their lifetime. So, by the time you come to use the reference `_f` it will be dangling.

If you want to take a copy of a `float`, use a `float` data member, not a `float&`. If you want a reference data member, you must make sure it refers to something that will still exist when the reference is used.

> if the code not compile, it is because is a pseudo-code from a real code

The correct way to deal with this is to write a short, complete program including the code you want to ask about, check that it compiles, and then ask a question about your complete program. There are at least two compilation problems with the code you posted. Your real code (if it compiles in g++) cannot possibly initialize the reference the way that you have done in your sample code.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but if I could make a float insted of a float& I would have done it. I think the question reflect the problem, and I know in fact this float(NaN) do not compile. I know that link temporal values that is already writen in the question, and that is my problem. I just wnat to know if there is a way or not to do it

Comment: @user1739342: if you need a copy and you also need a reference, then you could use two data members. `struct Foo { float fval; float &fref; Foo(float f) : fval(f), fref(fval) {} };`. But I don't really see the point -- if you take a copy then you can just use the copy, I can't think why you would also need a reference data member that refers to the copy. Since you won't show the use of this reference, you aren't going to get any advice about it.

Comment: is complicated. I is a cuestion of inherence, I want that that the child class point the same place that it father. That means I when the child class constructor using a object of the father class the internal values must point to the same locations. Because I want when the father object is change is children copy object change too. I will like to do it without change must of the father class implementation

Comment: @user1739342: if you want the parent and child to point to *the same object*, then they can't take copies. A copy is not the same object. Maybe your constructor should take a reference, or maybe your whole idea is wrong, I don't know

Comment: Yep, that why I want the reference, I want the father class object have a value, and the child class object just reference the object of the object father class. The only way to make the child is by give an object of the father class. It might not be posible without pinters but I want to find out

Comment: @user1739342: When you talk about "child" and "father", do you mean derived and base classes? If so, do you know that derived classes can access data members of their base classes, if the member is `public` or `protected`?

Comment: yes,I tried to set it as protected. But don't the compiler dont allow me to access too the elements it sed something like "dont have access to the protected element" I dont remember, I mean I can access to the protected elements of "this" but not of other object send as parameter of the constructor. I already read about this. This is why I come to the idea to try to do the reference thing at the father side. For now I change strategy I breake the inherence, and the child have a reference to the an object (the father), I acctualy simulate inherence behavor. If you have better idea I am open